# How to prevent Angular2 from using route '/'

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes, angular2-routing

I am wanting to use Angular2 for data binding with Firebase in an express application. I only want Angular2 to take routes that are not defined by Express, including "/". I have the route defined as such in express:

```
app.get("/", app.locals.authenticated, routes.home);
```

But Angular2 is taking responsibility for the route. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Is the app.get("/", ...) route defined before any routes that send your JS bundle/files?

Comment: I feel like a dunce. I have middleware defined to statically serve the angular directory before the line in the post. Removing it seemed to fix the problem. Thank you very much @dkimot

Comment: Okay, I'll toss a short answer on for anyone else who finds this on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining Connect style middleware you need to ensure that any JS files that handle routing, through any framework (Angular, React, etc.), can take over routes that you want your server to handle. This is often caused by serving static files first then adding "controller" type routes afterward, such as a route at the root.